# VHDL testbench not changing output ALU 32bit

Tags: vhdl, alu, test-bench

You see, I've already finished to describe an ALU on vhdl with modelsim, however the testbench seems to not update the solution, when I see the simulation the circuit 32 bit response always says `"UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU"` I dont know what did i wrote wrong on the testbench also there is a warning on the compiler about the circuit response which says

> ** Warning: (vsim-8683) Uninitialized out port /alu_tb/ALU_test/res(32 downto 0) has no driver.
>     This port will contribute value (UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU) to the signal network.

and here is the testbench code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity ALU_tb is        
end ALU_tb;

architecture bhv_ALU_tb of ALU_tb is
component ALU
    port(
        a, b: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        c: in std_logic;
        s: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        res: out std_logic_vector(32 downto 0));
end component;

signal a, b: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal c: std_logic;
signal s: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal re: std_logic_vector(32 downto 0);

begin 
    ALU_test: ALU port map (a => a, b => b, c => c, s => s, res => re);
process begin
    b <= "00000000000010100111010100011110";
    a <= "00000000011010000100110011101110";
    c <= '0';
    s <= "1111";
    wait for 2 ns;
    b <= "00000000000010100111010100011110";
    a <= "00000000011010000100110011101110";
    c <= '0';
    s <= "0100";
    wait for 2 ns;
    s <= "0000";
    wait for 2 ns;
    s <= "0001";
    wait for 2 ns;
    s <= "0010";
    wait for 2 ns;
    s <= "0011";
    wait for 2 ns;
    s <= "0100";
    wait for 2 ns;
    s <= "0101";
    wait for 2 ns;
    s <= "0110";
    wait for 2 ns;
    s <= "0111";
    wait for 2 ns;
    s <= "1000";
    wait for 2 ns;
    s <= "1001";
    wait for 2 ns;
    s <= "1010";
    wait for 2 ns;
    s <= "1011";
    wait for 2 ns;
    s <= "1100";
    wait for 2 ns;
    s <= "1101";
    wait for 2 ns;
    s <= "1110";
    wait for 2 ns;
    s <= "1111";
    wait for 2 ns;
end process;
end bhv_ALU_tb;
```

i know the mistake seems trivial "res isn't initialized" but I've been away from vhdl way too long and honestly dont know how to fix it, any ideas?

Comment: The answer to this question is inside your component - `res` is out value, so if it is not connected to anything inside it, it is not driven from inside the module.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly

```
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
```

Bad.. don't use. You don't even need them in this file.
*If* you ever need arithmentic, use `numeric_std`.

Then: the error is in the component `ALU`, becasue that should 'drive' `res`. But since you did not post the code of that, we cannot help you (yet).

p.s. currently you do not need to define a component in VHDL anymore. You could just write:

```
ALU_test: entity work.ALU port map
```